# nodejs - single login for many different apps

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I have one **auth** app using Passport and Express and it works as well on `localhost:3000`.

Now I have 6 other apps that needs the authentication.

How can I integrate them as a single login, like google?

Maybe using some cookie? Or any kind of shared session (does this exists?)

Comment: The other apps have to be on subdomains

Comment: all apps are subdomains. so?

Comment: You will need to set for the cookies .mydomain.com, and then set headers such as access-allow-credentials. But I'm not an expert